# Swift: Rounded corners appear different upon first appearance and reappearing

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ApplyCorners: UIButton {
override func didMoveToWindow() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
}
}
```

I apply this class to the buttons in my application and it is working great, but when I apply it to a button used in every cell in a table view the button corners are not round upon entering the view, but if I click one of the buttons I get segued to another view. If I then segue back the corners are "fixed" / round.

The green is the button when returning and the red is upon first entering the view.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest `layoutSubviews`, which captures whenever the `frame` of the button changes:

```
class ApplyCorners: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
    }

}
```

This takes care of both the original appearance and any subsequent appearance. It also avoids all sorts of problems related to not only whether the `frame` was known when the view appeared, but also if you do anything that might change the size of the button (e.g. anything related to constraints, rotation events, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is likely to be a timing problem. Consider the phrase `self.frame.height`. At the time `didMoveToWindow` is called, we may not yet *know* our frame. If you are going to call a method that depends upon layout, do so when layout has actually occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna propose another alternative: listen to any bounds changes. This avoids the problem of wondering "is my frame set yet when this is called?"

```
class ApplyCorners: UIButton {

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
        }
    }

}
```

Edited `frame` to `bounds` because as @Rob points out, listening for frame changes will cause you to miss the initial load sometimes.

Comment: If you use constraints, this can sometimes result in `frame` not getting set directly, and thus this `cornerRadius` is not set. (See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/4fe84eb264225711f2ae017b379b04c6.) If you're looking for this "round corners whenever frame changes", you really have to do it in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @Rob Thanks good catch. I had actually noticed that in projects before and noted that observing `bounds` instead of `frame` always calls the `didSet` (tested in your gist).

Answer (score 0):

Putting your code in `didMoveToWindow()` does not make sense to me. I'd suggest implementing `layoutSubviews()` instead. That method gets called any time a view object's layout changes, so it should update if you resize your view.

(Changed my suggestion based on comments from TNguyen and and Rob.)

Comment: Is there not still a chance that the frame is still incorrect at `awakeFromNib()`

Comment: If the frame changes then the layer should still draw correctly. When you set a property like layer.cornerWidth the layer draws correctly as frame of the view changes (At least for a view's content layer. If you add other sublayers to a view those don't resize with the view's frame.)

Comment: no but he's not setting it to a static number but a dynamic one. And I'm guessing by OP's post it's obvious that he wants it to be a circle (i.e. he wants to corner radius it by half of the width).

Comment: I see your and TNguyen's point. That way you can dynamically adjust the view's corner radius to keep it set to 1/2 the view's height. I wasn't thinking about dynamically sized views.